# Need a help in understanding a solution of a third problem in Israel Gohberg.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, proof-explanation

The question and its solution is given in the following picture:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I do not understand the following items:

1- what is $0_{V}$, and why the  $0_{V}$ in $L_{2}[a,b]$ is the function zero almost everywhere? why  $0_{V}$ can not be the function that is identically zero? could anyone clarify this for me please?

2-In the forth line from below, Why the author take specially $f \chi_{s^{c}}$? and why he took $\chi$ on $S^{c}$ ?  and why is he sure that it belongs to $kerA$?

3-In the second line from below, Why the author take the integration over $S^{c}$ ? and why he changed the bound of the integration from $S^{c}$ to B?and what is the meaning of the measure of an operator to be equal zero $i.e. m(B) = 0 $, could anyone clarify this for me please?

Thank you!

Comment: The elements of $L^2[a,b]$ are not functions but equivalence classes of functions. The class of functions that is the zero in $L^2[a,b]$ are all those functions that are zero almost everywhere. This includes the zero function. $0_v$ likely means zero vector, every vector space has exactly one zero-vector.

Comment: @s.harp  could you please take a look at the other 2 questions and answer them if you have time ?

Comment: @s.harp https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579859/need-a-help-in-understanding-a-solution-of-a-forth-problem-in-israel-gohberg?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Idontknow probably not today, as it is new years eve. If they are still unanswered I will answer them tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

1) @s. harp has answered the question why the zero element $0_{V}$ need no be the zero function in the sense of everywhere zero. Another way to view it is that, if it were the case that we set $0_{V}$ to be the everywhere zero function, then the function, $\chi_{\{a\}}$ which takes value $1$ at $x=a$ and zero otherwise, still satisfies that $\|\chi_{\{a\}}\|_{L^{2}[a,b]}=0$, then $L^{2}$ is not a normed space. So the virtue by setting $0_{V}$ to be the equivalent class of almost everywhere zero is to guarantee that $L^{2}[a,b]$ is really a normed space.

2) We have $(Af\chi_{S^{c}})(t)=a(t)f(t)\chi_{S^{c}}(t)=a(t)f(t)$ if $t\in S^{c}$ and $=0$ if $t\in S$. For $t\in S^{c}$, then by the definition of $S$, we must have $a(t)=0$, so $a(t)f(t)=0$. Whether or not $t\in S^{c}$, we have $a(t)f(t)\chi_{S^{c}}(t)=0$, so $Af\chi_{S^{c}}=0$ (in this case, we are lucky, that $Af\chi_{S^{c}}$ is the zero everywhere), so $f\chi_{S^{c}}\in\ker(A)$.

The reason to look at $\chi_{S^{c}}$ is to justify that $f(t)=0$ almost everywhere on $S^{c}$, one way to prove this is sufficiently to show that $\displaystyle\int_{S^{c}}|f(t)|^{2}dt=0$. The strategy is the following. Because by assumption we have $f\in(\ker A)^{\perp}$, so $\left<f,g\right>=0$ for any $g\in\ker(A)$, then we just put $g=f\chi_{S^{c}}$, so get $\left<f,f\chi_{S^{c}}\right>=0$, expanding the definition of $\left<f,f\chi_{S^{c}}\right>$ we get $\displaystyle\int_{S^{c}}|f(t)|^{2}dt$, so $\displaystyle\int_{S^{c}}|f(t)|^{2}dt=0$ is then obtained.

3) You have misunderstoof the notation. In this case, $B=S^{c}$ is simply the set notation, it is not the operator $B$ introduced at the very beginning. So the domain of integration is not changed. Well, sometimes we just run out of notation and we may accidentally repeat some notation.