# Need a help in understanding a solution of a forth problem in Israel Gohberg.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, proof-explanation

The question and part of its solution is given in the following picture:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The operator in Question(9) is given in the following link:

[Need a help in understanding a solution of a third problem in Israel Gohberg.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578814/need-a-help-in-understanding-a-solution-of-a-third-problem-in-israel-gohberg)

1-But it is not clear for me the correction for the question that the author wrote, what is the difference in meaning between the condition that $a \neq 0_{V}$ and the condition that $a(t) \neq 0$ for $t \in [a,b]$, could anyone clarify this for me please?

2-In the forth line in the solution, it is not clear for me from where the last equality come,could anyone explain this for me please?

3- In the fifth line in the solution, I do not understand from where the author concluded what he wrote in this line, could anyone explain this for me please?

4-I do not understand in the proof of the direction $\Rightarrow $ why he put $m(A_{n}) = 0$, could anyone explain this for me please?

5-I do not understand in the proof of the direction $\Rightarrow $ the forth line from below, could anyone explain this for me please?

6-I do not understand in the proof of the direction $\Rightarrow $ why $g(t) = 0$ if $a(t) = 0$, could anyone explain this for me please?

7-I do not understand in the proof of the direction $\Rightarrow $ what is the general idea he exactly uses, could anyone explain this for me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) $a\ne 0_{V}$ means that it is not the case that $a$ is zero almost everywhere, but it could have zeroes somewhere. Take for example, $a(t)=(t-1)^{2}$, $a(1)=0$, so $a$ has zero somewhere (only one zero for this function) and apparently $a$ is not zero almost everywhere. That $a(t)\ne 0$ for $t\in[a,b]$ is a very strong statement, which means that $a$ cannot have any zero.

2) If $Af\in L^{2}[a,b]$, then by the very definition of $L^{2}$, we have $\displaystyle\int_{[a,b]}|a(t)f(t)|^{2}dt<\infty$. Now $|a|$ is a continuous real-valued function, as $a$ has no zero at all, it cannot be the case that $\inf_{t\in S}|a(t)|=0$

(if not, you can find a sequence $(t_{n})$ such that $|a(t_{n})|\rightarrow 0$ and $t_{n}\in[a,b]$, one may find a convergent subsequence $(t_{n_{k}})$ with limit $t_{0}\in[a,b]$, then taking $k\rightarrow\infty$, one has by continuity that $|a(t_{0})|=0$, which contradicts our assumption).

Now $\dfrac{1}{|a(t)|}\leq M:=\dfrac{1}{\inf_{t\in S}|a(t)|}$, then $\displaystyle\int_{S}\left|\dfrac{f(t)}{a(t)}\right|^{2}dt\leq M^{2}\int_{S}|f(t)|^{2}dt\leq\int_{[a,b]}|f(t)|^{2}dt<\infty$.

3) If $\text{Im}(A)$ is closed, then $\overline{\text{Im}(A)}\subseteq\text{Im}(A)$ (actually it is the equality), but the elements $f$ of $\overline{\text{Im}(A)}$ satisfy $f(t)=0$ almost everywhere on $S^{c}$, then clearly $\displaystyle\int_{S^{c}}\left|\dfrac{f(t)}{a(t)}\right|^{2}dt=\int_{S^{c}}0 dt=0<\infty$.

Suppose that $\displaystyle\int_{S^{c}}\left|\dfrac{f(t)}{a(t)}\right|^{2}dt<\infty$, we are to prove that $\overline{\text{Im}(A)}\subseteq\text{Im}(A)$ (then $\text{Im}(A)$ is closed). So assume also that $f\in\text{Im}(A)$, then the definition shows that $f(t)=0$ almost everywhere on $S^{c}$, so two conditions of being an element of $\text{Im}(A)$ are satisfied, so $f\in\text{Im}(A)$, we are done.

4) Actually the author wrote $m(A_{n})>0$, and this is not necessarily true for all $n$, because $A_{n}$ could be the emptyset. Of course one needs to modify a little to the subsequent argument by the author: One lets $N$ to be the set all $n$ such that $m(A_{n})>0$, then set $g(t)=\displaystyle\sum_{n\in N}\dfrac{\chi_{A_{n}}(t)}{n\sqrt{\alpha_{n}}}$, the same reasoning given by the author still shows that $g\in L^{2}[a,b]$.

5) Note that all $A_{n}$ and $B$ are disjoint, so splitting the domain of integration $[a,b]$ to be $A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup\cdots\cup A_{n}\cup\cdots\cup B$, we have $\displaystyle\int_{[a,b]}|g(t)|^{2}dt=\int_{A_{1}}|g(t)|^{2}dt+\cdots+\int_{A_{n}}|g(t)|^{2}dt+\cdots+\int_{B}|g(t)|^{2}dt=\displaystyle\sum_{n}\int_{A_{n}}|g(t)|^{2}dt+0$ since $\displaystyle\int_{B}|g(t)|^{2}dt=\int_{B}0^{2}dt=0$.

6) If $a(t)=0$, for this $t$, we have $t\notin A_{n}$ for all $n$, so $\chi_{A_{n}}(t)=0$ for all $n$ and hence $g(t)=\displaystyle\sum_{n}\dfrac{\chi_{A_{n}}(t)}{n\sqrt{\alpha_{n}}}=\sum_{n}\dfrac{0}{n\sqrt{\alpha_{n}}}=0$.

7) The idea is a kind of proof by contradiction. The set $N$ in my 4) has infinitely many elements (so $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in N}\dfrac{2^{2n}}{n^{2}}=\infty$). The reason is the following. Since $a$ takes the value zero at some point $t$, around this point, say, $s\in(t-\delta,t+\delta)$, the value of $|a(s)|<\dfrac{M}{2^{2}}$, if $a(s)=0$, then all such $s$ belongs to $A_{n}$ for all $n\geq 2$, if $a(s)\ne 0$, then maybe that $\dfrac{M}{2^{5}}<|a(s)|\leq\dfrac{M}{2^{4}}$, then $4\in N$. Proceed in this way, we choose another neighbourhood of $t$, say, $(t-\delta',t+\delta')$ such that $|a(u)|<\dfrac{M}{2^{5}}$ for all $u\in(t-\delta',t+\delta')$, once again we consider if $a(u)=0$ if so, we are good, if not, let say, $\dfrac{M}{2^{?+1}}<|a(u)|\leq\dfrac{M}{2^{?}}$, then $?\in N$, and these steps can be continued infinitely, so $N$ is an infinite set.

If it were $a$ taking no any zero, then such $N$ can be only finitely many elements, then the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in N}\dfrac{2^{2n}}{n^{2}}$ is convergent, no contradiction is obtained.

CORRECTION:

Actually no $A_{n}$ could be the emptyset. For $|a(v_{1})|=M$, and $|a(v_{2})|=0$, then $|a|$ assumes every value between $[0,M]$, this is by Intermediate Value Theorem. Having assume some value $|a(s)|$ with $\dfrac{M}{2^{n}}<|a(s)|<\dfrac{M}{2^{n-1}}$, then as $|a|$ is continuous, in a small enough neighbourhood of $s$, $|a|$ takes the value in between $\dfrac{M}{2^{n}}$ and $\dfrac{M}{2^{n-1}}$, so $A_{n}$ contains the neighbourhood (the so called neighbourhood can be taken as an interval) so $m(A_{n})\geq\text{the length of the interval}>0$. So the set $N$ in my 4) is actually the set of all positive integers.