# Finding the norm of an integral operator.

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces, integral-operators

Let $H = L_{2}([-\pi,\pi])$. For each $m \in \mathbb{N^{*}}$ and define  $T_{m}:H \rightarrow H$ by $$T_{m}(f)(t) = \frac{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(s) \sin(2m (s+t)) ds}{2^m},$$
Let $T = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} T_{m}$.

Find $||T_{m}||$?

Could anyone help me finding this norm please?

Comment: is $\mid\mid T_m\mid\mid$ or $\mid\mid T\mid\mid$?

Comment: $||T_{m}||$ @MartínVacasVignolo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is not a complete solution for the question.

Let $f(s)=u(s)+iv(s)$, then
\begin{align*}
f(s)\sin(2m(s+t))&=u(s)\sin(2m(s+t))+iv(s)\sin(2m(s+t))\\
&=(u(s)\sin 2ms)\cos 2mt+(u(s)\cos 2ms)\sin 2mt\\
&~~~~+i[(v(s)\sin 2ms)\cos 2mt+(v(s)\cos 2ms)\sin 2mt].
\end{align*}
Let 
\begin{align*}
& A=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}u(s)\sin(2ms)ds\\
& B=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}u(s)\cos(2ms)ds\\
& C=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}v(s)\sin(2ms)ds\\
& D=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}v(s)\cos(2ms)ds,
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
&2^{m}\|T_{m}(f)\|_{L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]}\\
&=\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(A\cos 2mt+B\sin 2mt)^{2}+(C\cos 2mt+D\sin 2mt)^{2}dt\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(A^{2}+C^{2})\cos^{2}(2mt)+(B^{2}+D^{2})\sin^{2}(2mt)+2AB\sin(2mt)\cos(2mt)\\
+2CD\sin(2mt)\cos(2mt)dt\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}(A^{2}+C^{2})\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}1+\cos(4mt)dt+\dfrac{1}{2}(B^{2}+D^{2})\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}1-\cos(4mt)dt\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}(A^{2}+C^{2})2\pi+\dfrac{1}{2}(B^{2}+D^{2})2\pi\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}(A^{2}+B^{2}+C^{2}+D^{2})^{1/2}.
\end{align*}
However,
\begin{align*}
A^{2}+B^{2}&=\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}u(s)(\cos(2ms)+i\sin(2ms))ds\right|^{2}\\
&=\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}u(s)e^{2mis}ds\right|^{2}\\
&\leq 2\pi\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|u(s)|^{2}ds\right)\\
&= 2\pi\|u\|_{L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]}^{2},
\end{align*}
similarly, 
\begin{align*}
C^{2}+D^{2}\leq 2\pi\|v\|_{L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
A^{2}+B^{2}+C^{2}+D^{2}\leq 2\pi(\|u\|_{L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]}+\|v\|_{L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]})=2\pi\|f\|_{L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]}^{2},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
(A^{2}+B^{2}+C^{2}+D^{2})^{1/2}\leq\sqrt{2\pi}\|f\|_{L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]}.
\end{align*}
Summing up what we have, then
\begin{align*}
\|T_{m}\|=\sup_{f\ne 0}\dfrac{\|T_{m}(f)\|_{L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]}}{\|f\|_{L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]}}\leq\sup_{f\ne 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\pi\cdot 2^{-m}\|f\|_{L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]}}{\|f\|_{L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{2^{m}}.
\end{align*}

Guess: To obtain the bound $\sqrt{2}\pi/2^{m}$, it might be having something to do with the Fourier coefficients of $u$ and $v$, but I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: why you put $\leq$ in the second step? what did you do?

Comment: Is not $|\int f(x)| \leq \int |f(x)|$ by the triangle inequality?

Comment: why u did not use the absolute value square in the definition of the norm but u used the ordinary bracket square >>>> is not $f$ may be a complex function?

Comment: "Is not $|∫f(x)|≤∫|f(x)|$ by the triangle inequality?" this is just a general question ......it is not related to your solution ......I know you have used Holder inequality.

Comment: for complex valued case it is not applicable you mean?

Comment: what is the more argument that it requires?

Comment: If we put the absolute value in the definition of the norm , how can we get rid of it in the integration of $|\sin|^2$?

Comment: How is the integration of $\sin^{2}$ gives $2 \pi$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585984/verifying-a-certain-formula-about-the-image-and-kernel-of-the-adjoint-of-an-oper/2585989#2585989   could you look at this question for me please if you have time and provide more detailed solution ..... thanks in advance.

Comment: The first general fact that he uses it is prove is not known for me (or may be I have forgotten it)

Comment: Ok I will do thanks :)

Comment: In the line before last How you showed that $||T_{m}|| \geq \frac{\sqrt{2} \pi}{2^m}$ so that the equality holds, could you provide more detailes please?

Comment: My professor gave it to me in the trial exam

Comment: He did not said more than what I have written above

Comment: Does your professor provide you the answer? I get stuck above, that's all I can do. I would like to look at your professor's solution, that must be very amazing.

Comment: yes he gave me the following  hint :first use the formula for sin (x + y) = sin x cos y + cos x sin y, then put f(s) = sin ... , but I did not implement it until now.

Comment: Essentially your professor's idea is similar of my proof above. The point is, is that the operator norm exactly $\sqrt{2}\pi/2^{m}$?

Comment: I will work on my professor idea and see ..... he did not said to me that its norm is exactly the value you mentioned..... or I did not ask him this direct question but I will meet him on 4/1 to discuss the solutions ........Happy new year :)

Comment: Thank u sooo much for your help ..... I will read your above proof please do not erase it ...... why did you erase the first part that was written?

Comment: Three hours ago. Actually the above proof, the bound is still the same.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579859/need-a-help-in-understanding-a-solution-of-a-forth-problem-in-israel-gohberg  >>>> could u look at this when you have time please?

Comment: Also   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578814/need-a-help-in-understanding-a-solution-of-a-third-problem-in-israel-gohberg?noredirect=1&lq=1